# ArangoDB Connection error from python

Tags: arangodb

Trying to connect to ArangoDB using python

Code:

```
from pyArango.connection import *
conn = Connection(username="root", password="XXXXX")
```

Got below error

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:/Python/Nlp/imageTotext.py", line 177, in <module>
    conn = Connection(username="root", password="XXXXX")   File "C:\Users\am843946\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pyArango\connection.py",
line 105, in __init__
    self.reload()   File "C:\Users\am843946\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pyArango\connection.py",
line 124, in reload
    data = r.json()   File "C:\Users\am843946\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pyArango\connection.py",
line 19, in __call__
    raise e  ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: @AndrewGrothe his first time of code ```from pyArango.connection import *``` tells us he's using the pyArango library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to specify a connection URL like that?

```
conn = Connection(arangoURL="http://localhost:8529", username="root", password="")
```

That way it should work.